# In Preview/Test, Core Web Vitals data populates the GA4 debug timeline too frequently and makes it hard to see the other events

Tags: tags, preview

I'm trying to reduce the number of times I see Core Web Vitals data (CLS, FID, LCP)on the G4 debug timeline. The Core Web Vitals data fires and is correct but I don't need to see it so many times. The data points clutters the debug timeline and makes it hard to see the other events that also fired in Google Tag Manager when testing in Preview Mode.